# Some Remapped Keyboard Shortcuts in tmux Not Working After macOS 13.4.1 Update

Tags: macos, tmux

Is anybody else having problems with remapped keyboard shortcuts after the macOS update? My pane resizing is not working. I'm using a really old `.tmux.conf` and some of it I don't understand anymore. I just started coding again in April after not coding for years.

I don't know what else to try except disabling the remapping for resizing. This is the part where all the bindings are in my `.tmux.conf` currently:

```
# Remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# Use vim navigation keys
# setw -g mode-keys vi

# Remap selection, yanking, and copy to clipboard
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi Enter send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'

# Map clear-history to Ctrl + k
bind -n C-k clear-history

# Split panes using | and -
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %
```

It's still not working after that. I was expecting that the pane navigation would work. I tried CTRL + a with the arrow keys but it's not resizing. I've also forgotten the default pane resizing. When I googled it, the answers were my pane navigation. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the difference between commenting things out and a blank .tmux.conf?

Comment: I found this command `tmux list-keys` and resizing the pane is listed as `bind-key -r -T prefix       C-Up                 resize-pane -U`. Does anyone know which key it is? From how I'm reading it, it sounds like it's bound to Control + Up, which is a keyboard shortcut for macOS's Spaces. This setting `setw -g mode-keys vi` is for Vim navigation, right? From what I know, `vi` is a shortcut for Vim.